Why is it when I try weight-paint one part of the mesh, all the other bones are also weight painted in that section to
[When I weight painted on the hand bone, the elbow bone also got weight painted on that section even though I didn't press Alt on it.

Hello, it's hard to understand, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

This purple color doesn't represent weight: it's only a warning about the fact that no vertex group is associated with the selected bone.
As soon as you use a weight brush, a new vertex group is created with the correct name.

file:///C:/Users/olivi/Downloads/Untitled%20(31).png ( I added weight to the bone but it still kept the weight from the hand bone and put it into the elbow bone. That might have not been very clear but that's the best I can explain it with my knowledge.)

@Olivia gamble you have not given a correct link to the file, please use https://blend-exchange.com/ and read the instructions

Ok, I used Blend-Exchange.
